# High CPU temperatue on Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

I've recently bought myself a Macbook Pro 13" Retina Mid 2014 model.
I went for the cheapest model but upgraded the CPU from 2.6Ghz to 2.8GHz. The specs are:

- 2.8GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.3GHz
- 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L SDRAM
- 128GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
- Intel Iris Graphics

I enjoy playing Football Manager 2014 which is very heavy on the CPU because it's a simulation based game. When running Football Manager my CPU often is 90+ degrees celcius.

Now I'm sitting next to my brother who has a Macbook Pro Retina Early 2014 model - almost the exact same hardware - the only difference is that my CPU is better than his which is 2.6GHz.

He too is playing Football Manager with the exact same settings as me but his CPU temperature rarely gets above 75+ degrees celcius. It's no so much the temperature that bothers me but the noise from the fan.

How can that be?

Even browsing StackExchange keeps the CPU temperature on a steady 70 degrees celcius.

None of us are running any heavy apps and the Activity Monitor shows nothing special other than FM14 taking a lot of the CPU.

I've tried to do a SMC reset (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) and a hardware test (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) with no result.

Both temperatures are read with smcFanControl.

Comment: Check your CPU using the Intel gadget tool. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20

Comment: Hmm, it logs the same temperature as smcFanControl - are there any other functions in this program?

Comment: IS it actually running at high power usage?

Comment: The "Current Package Power" often spikes to 25W when under load - is that what you meant?